# Transforming c function with decimal and static into assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I need help to transform this c code into assembly code. I am not sure how to work with the static and the 0.5. I know I can use shift right logical to get 0.5, but not sure how to do that.

```
int my_func(int in)
{
  static int w_old = 0;

  int w = in + 0.5*w_old;
  int out = w - w_old;
  w_old = w;
    
  return out;
}
```

I tried to do using division and then I tried to print to see if I would get 0.5. But I get 4.9E-324.

```
.text


li $t1,1  
li $t2,2 
    
    
mtc1 $t1, $f12
mtc1 $t2, $f30

div.d $f2,$f12,$f30
        

li $v0, 3 
mov.d  $f4, $f2
syscall

.data
message1: .asciiz "division is "
```

Comment: You can try to see how compilers do that.

Comment: For the static, just make it a global.

Comment: For integer division by 2, shift right by 1.

Comment: @ErikEidt Note that the rounding differs if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's look at what this line does:

```
int w = in + 0.5*w_old;
```

In C, this will use double precision floating point for both the multiplication and the addition — in order to do that it will convert both `w_old` and `in` from integer to double.  Since the assignment is back to an integer, the result will be convert back to integer.  So, two conversions of integer to double and one conversion back.

If floating point rounding is important to you then use floating point processor instructions and multiply by 0.5 or divide by 2 and do the addition in float as well, just as written in C.

Otherwise, since this line converts integers to double, and then back to integer, you could do the division and addition without going to floating point, with the only difference being rounding.

For example, 501/2=250 in integer division, but 501/2=250.5 in floating point, which may round to 251 as an integer.  (One can also do the rounding of simple division by 2 in integer form as well.)

So, you have to choose which behavior you want.  Do you want double or to shift?  Either way the assignment to `w` needs an integer.

---

> how do I shift right by 1?

Yes, `srl` can be used to shift right by 1, but that will to a logical shift, which is appropriate for unsigned numbers, whereas `sra` will do an arithmetic shift, which is appropriate for signed numbers.

The difference may not matter to your use case, but the C code is written using signed integers.  If a negative number is shifted using `srl` it will become a large positive number, so mathematically that is problematic.

If you don't have negative numbers and they are small you can use either one.

Let's also note that shifting -1 to the right arithmetically by 1, will stay -1 rather than going to 0 as we would expect from integer division.  So, compilers use a couple of instructions to deal with that corner case (something like adding 1 to negative numbers before shifting).

Comment: *which may round to 251 as an integer.*  Not in C.  double->int conversion truncates toward 0 unless you use a C function like `long lrint(double)` or `(int)nearbyint(x)`.  (Same as integer division, unlike arithmetic right shift which rounds towards -inf so is different for negative numbers.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But still struggling in how to write this line in assembly -> int w = in + 0.5*w_old; I need to get the 0.5 by using division or shift right logical.

Comment: @p20xx: You should not be using *logical* right shift.  Your C uses signed `int`, not `unsigned`, so if you're optimizing away the FP stuff to just use integer shifts, it should be arithmetic `sra`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I understand your point, but that's what I need to work with. What I really want is just to understand how can I do that. I am looking videos and reading, but I just get the theory and not many examples in how this is done.

Comment: @Erik: unfortunately neither GCC nor clang with `-O3 -ffast-math` managed to optimize the `(int)(x + 0.5*y)` into pure integer: https://godbolt.org/z/xjGq3T9KE (for x86-64 because that has newer gcc/clang versions than Godbolt's MIPS GCC install).  I think such an optimization would be possible without violating the as-if rule, given that `double` is IEEE binary64 and thus has enough mantissa bits to never do any rounding when adding two int->double conversion results, except in the final conversion back to `int`.  And 0.5 is exactly representable, no rounding there either.

Comment: @p20xx: why do you "need" to implement the asm in a way that doesn't match the C source?  Does something specifically tell you that you're allowed to assume the input numbers are always non-negative?

Comment: I think `in + w_old/2` might be exactly equivalent for all `int` input values of `in` and `w_old`, even negative, since I don't think it matters if a `-0.5` or `+0.5` is truncated to 0 before or after integer addition.  In that case https://godbolt.org/z/cadh5TTs3 shows asm that exactly implements the function semantics per the as-if rule.  To simplify it to just use one sra or srl instead of using srl+sra to do signed `w_old/2`, use a C right shift `in + (w_old>>1)` or use `unsigned int`

Comment: No wait, that's not right.  `-1 + 1/2` = -1 + 0 = -1.  But `-1 + 0.5*1` = `-0.5` which rounds to `0`.  So optimizing to pure integer might take 64-bit integers for `(2*in + w_old)/2` without overflow, or some extra logic to do something equivalent for same-width signed int without overflow.